# Checking for machine precision in Solvers

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

When I run a solver to solve for x given y and the relationship y = f(x), we have to keep checking if previous guess of x and the current guess of x atleast differ by the machine precision. What is the most efficient way of doing this in C++?

If I have x1 and x2, then I want to check if mantissa(x1) - mantisaa(x2) < 1e-14 or 2^-equivalent.  Is there a predefined function which does this check for us? I did notice a stackoverflow response that tells us an efficient way to get the mantissa of floating point using unions. But, is there a machine independent implementation of this in boost or gsl etc.

Comment: Have a look at 'frexp'

Comment: I am Just curious, why don't you check **abs(x2-x1)**?